# JSON from django rest Framework

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework, jsonserializer

I'm making  a API with django rest framework, but the JSON has the
 the categoria's id of categoria model, the foreignkey, 
I want  show  the categoria's name  equals the model's id

```
class Establecimiento(models.Model):
    nombre= models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Categoria(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
```

I have a file serializers.py a views.py whit ViewSet

```
class EstablecimientoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#    establecimiento = Establecimineto.objects.values('categoira__titulo')
    class Meta:
        model = Establecimiento.objects.select_related('categoria')
#      model = Establecimiento
        fields = ('nombre','categoria',)
```

#

```
class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
#    queryset = Establecimiento.objects.all()
    queryset = Establecimiento.objects.values('nombre','categoria__titulo')
    serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer
```

Then when I make the query in the views.py the  JSON  result only show the fields null
where I should  make the query for  that the JSON resulting not show id the Foreignkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your serializer should be defined:

```
class EstablecimientoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categoria = serializers.RelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Establecimiento
        depth = 1
        fields = ('nombre', 'categoria',)
```

and the viewset:

```
class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Establecimiento.objects.only('nombre','categoria',)
    serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer
```

This assumes that you have defined `__unicode__` method for `Categoria`:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
    # fields..

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

If you don't want to define `__unicode__`, you can instead of `RelatedField` use the `SlugRelatedField` field:

```
categoria = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='titulo')
```